# How can I increment a number input?

Tags: javascript, html, html-input

When using HTML `input` elements I tried implementing the `step` attribute. This allowed me to add 100 to the current value by clicking the up/down arrows in the input field.

However, `step` determines legal values, so it won't work for simple increments. For example, if I type in 123, it will increase to 200, not 223.

```js
// populate field
document.querySelector("input").value = "123";
```

```html
<input type="number" step="100" value="0"/>
```

Is there an easy workaround for an increment/decrement function for the `input` element?

Comment: `step` is not just increments, it also implies that values must be a multiple of `step`.

Comment: Should be easy enough to write a function that increments/decrements by the step you want without using the step attribute

Comment: @fordat How would that help?

Comment: @Barmar you are correct, `step` determines legal values.

Comment: @j08691 I was wondering if writing a increment function would be unnecessary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`step` pushes away from the attribute:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.value = 123;
input.setAttribute('value', 123);
```

```html
<input type="number" step="100">
```

**UPDATE:**
Also, as @Barmar and @SebastianSimon pointed out, you can use `defaultValue`:

```js
input.defaultValue = 123;
```

Comment: Don't just post code, explain what was wrong and how you fixed it.

Comment: Specifically, it's based on the initial `value` attribute.

Comment: @Barmar sorry, I'll write the code first, then I'll explain. But it seems so clear if `setAttribute` is specified. With best regards.

Comment: The initial value is the `defaultValue` property. No need to use `setAttribute`.

Comment: Yes, `defaultValue` also works. I'll add that to my answer if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const input = document.getElementById("myInput");
const incrementBtn = document.getElementById("incrementBtn");
const decrementBtn = document.getElementById("decrementBtn");

incrementBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  input.stepUp(100); // Increment the input value by 1
});

decrementBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  input.stepDown(100); // Decrement the input value by 1
});
```

```html
<input id="myInput" type="number" value="123" min="0" step="1" />
<button id="incrementBtn">Increment</button>
<button id="decrementBtn">Decrement</button>
```

Inside the callback functions, we use the built-in methods stepUp() and stepDown() to increment and decrement the input value by 100, respectively. These methods ensure the input value is modified correctly, regardless of the step attribute.